# MSP not updating files

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, msp

I have a typical question. I have one Major version 2.2.15.0, one MSP 2.2.15.14 and another MSP 2.2.15.103. MSP 2.2.15.14 target image is 2.2.15.0,  MSP 2.2.15.103 target image is also 2.2.15.0. MY issue is that when i apply 2.2.15.103 on top of 2.2.15.0 + 2.2.15.14 it is not updating files (just updating one file) (Please note installation is successful). It is working fine if i apply 2.2.15.103 on top of 2.2.15.0. Please note that i know MSI only recognize first three letters of version number. I also think that if i will create 2.2.15.103 with target image 2.2.15.14 it should work fine. I have also tried with reinstallmode = amus. What i saw suspicious in 2.2.15.103 unsuccessful installation log is that it is showing ProductVersion = 2.2.15.14, while it is showing ProductVersion = 2.2.15.103 in correct installation. Is there any possibility that i can make it error free even if target image is 2.2.15.0 or any tweak in pcp or msp?  Adding some of the logs.

```
PATCH SEQUENCER: verifying the applicability of QFE patch C:\Users\as002mi\Desktop\Product_22150_update3_hotfix1_103.msp against product code: {4C969971-80B5-42CB-A25E-BCE0B71C3F86}, product version: 2.2.15.0, product language 1033 and upgrade code: {87B6ECED-50F1-41C8-A1EF-7D3410068A58}
MSI (c) (90:C0) [22:59:21:484]: PATCH SEQUENCER: QFE patch C:\Users\as002mi\Desktop\Product_22150_update3_hotfix1_103.msp is applicable.
MSI (c) (90:C0) [22:59:21:484]: SequencePatches returns success.
MSI (c) (90:C0) [22:59:21:484]: Final Patch Application Order:
MSI (c) (90:C0) [22:59:21:484]: {B4AC992C-E78E-45FE-B484-8CCEA30EA494} - C:\Users\as002mi\Desktop\Product_22150_update3_hotfix1_103.msp
MSI (c) (90:C0) [22:59:21:484]: {E626FEBC-8795-4421-A465-7E93382D62ED} 


MSI (s) (78:C4) [22:59:23:450]: Note: 1: 2262 2: MsiAssembly 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (78:C4) [22:59:23:450]: Patch Modified Files List:
MSI (s) (78:C4) [22:59:23:450]: File = aspose.slides.dll: Final State = Install

Property(C): ProductName = Product2.2
Property(C): ProductVersion = 2.2.15.14
Property(C): ProgressType0 = install
Property(C): ProgressType1 = Installing
Property(C): ProgressType2 = installed
Property(C): ProgressType3 = installs
```

Comment: I have resolved issue by setting sequence in patchseqence table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved issue by setting sequence in patchseqence table